# Android: Error on notification API level

Tags: android, notifications, deprecated, android-notifications

I am developing an application in which I am using push notification and this is working fine. My API level min is 8 and the max is 19.

My code of generate notification is as follows :

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Here i am getting warning on two places:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
```

and

```
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
```

The warning is:
**The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated**
 and **The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent) from the type Notification is deprecated** respectively.

So I made changes in the code as:

```
Notification notification;

    int currentVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    int honeycombVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

    if (currentVersion >= honeycombVersion ){
        notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                        .setContentTitle(",App")
                                        .setContentText(message)
                                        .setSmallIcon(icon)
                                        .build();
    } else{
        notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    }
```

But now i am getting error in **if** as:

**Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.Notification.Builder** and the warning in **Else** part remains same.

What should i do now please guide.

Answer (score 0):

in your situation the best you can do is to add this check

```
int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (apiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
   // call the constructor available since api level 11
} else {
  // fallback call the old constructor
}
```

and add the `SuppressLint` annotation to make the warning/error disapper

Answer (score 0):

for the error of "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.Notification.Builder"

try to change this `minSdkVersion 8` to `minSdkVersion 11` on your build.gradle